# not able to remove class from div using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a wordpress website [enter link description here](http://molugu.com/yantraev/)

in mobile view, in homepage 2 of its sections are hiding, when i inspected its due to a class named 'wpb_animate_when_almost_visible', as the sections are from a template i am not able to remove the class directly from code and not able to assign a new id to the div, so i inspected it from browser and copied the id selector and did the following code:

```js
document.getElementById("#entry-div > section:nth-child(6) > div.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid.text-align-center-ms.ltx-sr.ltx-sr-effect-fade_in.ltx-sr-id-492454531.ltx-sr-el-list_el.ltx-sr-delay-200.ltx-sr-duration-300.ltx-sr-sequences-100 > div.wpb_animate_when_almost_visible.wpb_slideInLeft.slideInLeft.wpb_column.vc_column_container.vc_col-sm-6.vc_col-lg-3.vc_col-md-6.text-align-center-ms").classList.remove("wpb_animate_when_almost_visible");
```

however this is not working, can anyone please tell me how to fix it or how to remove this class from all elements, thanks in advance

Comment: is there more than 1 element?

Comment: `getElementById` vs. `querySelector`.

Comment: And the notice: this selector is very ugly, good luck with other debugging ;-)

Comment: there is  probably an option in the builder/editor of the theme to remove that function without coding?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath yes bro

Comment: @pavel the class is not getting removed bro

Comment: @johnSmith i checked the css an styling, not able to find this clas

Comment: Wordpress has options to hide sections for different views, i assume that is where the class is coming from, no need to add javascript for this

Comment: @RamondeVries how bro

Comment: The issue must be that this selector is way too short.

Comment: your selector is wrong, since it's missing spaces, and uses classes that don't show on the site when i inspect it. also, like others already said, the selector is way too long and depends on so many classes that could change with any wordpress change that even if it'll work now, it can break anytime in the near future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `querySelectorAll` which selects based on css style selector pattern.
Also you do not need such a long selector, just place the class name or parent div will suffice.
Then based on `querySelectorAll` returned list you need to loop through every element and remove the class.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#entry-div > section:nth-child(6) > .wpb_animate_when_almost_visible")
.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("wpb_animate_when_almost_visible");
```